# Zope 2: How to save an object in debug shell?

Tags: zope

I can add/remove objects to Zope in debug shell easily, like `app.manage_addProduct['OFS.Folder'].manage_addFolder('test')`.  However I can't figure out a way to persist the changes to the database.

Am I missing something obvious? TIA,

PS: I tried `app._p_changed=1` but after exiting the shell using `exit()`, the changes hadn't been persisted.

Comment: Did you commit your changes?  >>> import transaction; transaction.get().commit()  #??

Comment: That's it!  I didn't know how to acquire a trx and commit it.  Thank you!

Comment: The Zope publisher normally commits the transaction for you, for 20x or 30x responses. For error responses the transaction is aborted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You mean if I do for example 50 database operations, Zope will automatically commit them for me?

Comment: @BahmanM.: Exactly, as one transaction.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Interesting.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must commit the transaction, see: http://www.zodb.org/zodbbook/transactions.html

Comment: Wow!  That is a comprehensive guide.  I assume it applies to Zope2 as well, right?